# ggplot with overlapping X axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot which looks like this.[image]

```
 p2=ggplot(data=data1, aes(x=ID, y = value)) + 
 geom_line(group=1,color='steelblue', size=2) +  facet_wrap(~variable)+theme_economist() 


p2=p2+theme(text = element_text(size=10), axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))


p2
```

The issue is that, I am getting overlapping X labels in the X axis. Is there any way to get non overlapping X axis labels.

Comment: Do you need to show all of the labels? If not the `scale_x_discrete` has options to limit the set shown.

Comment: Hi @RichardTelford yes I need to show all the values in X axis, as they are unique IDs

Answer (score 7):

There is nice solution to this problem with ggplot2 version 3.3.0.

```
 scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge=3))
```

Here is an [example](https://datavizpyr.com/how-to-dodge-overlapping-text-on-x-axis-labels-in-ggplot2/)

Answer (score 2):

Try `+ coord_flip()` -- the labels might fit better and be more legible on the y-axis.

Answer (score 2):

How about?

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =45, hjust = 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all labels which overlap:

```
scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(check.overlap = TRUE))
```